# Ruby: Any gems for threadpooling?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rubygems, threadpool

Is there a gem for threadpooling anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience forking/process pooling is much more effective than thereadpooling in Ruby (assuming you do not need much in terms of thread communication). Some time ago I created a gem called process_pool, which is a very basic process pool with a file based job queue (you can check it out here: http://github.com/psyho/process_pool).

Answer (score 2):

I would try https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/ .

It's basically a port of the java.util.concurrent abstractions (including threadpools) to ruby -- except if you install it under Jruby, it'll *use* the java.util.concurrent stuff. So you can write code that'll work and do the same thing semantically (not neccesarily the same performance) under any ruby platform.

It also offers Futures, a higher level abstraction which may be more convenient to use than thread pools.