# Is there a better ruby thread pool lib

Tags: ruby, threadpool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby: Any gems for threadpooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624861/ruby-any-gems-for-threadpooling)

Is there a better ruby lib thread pool? I want to use the thread pool to help me manage their running behaviors like java thread pool.

Really I am not sure, so I hope you guys recommend something.

Comment: @sarnold Good question, though my guess is Ruby's built-in [`ThreadGroup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ThreadGroup.html).

Comment: @sarnold @phrogz, no. what i want is similar to what @andrew-grimm recommend.

Comment: There's a question about ThreadGroup (mentioned by @Phrogz) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944500/what-is-rubys-threadgroup-for

Comment: @andrew-grimm yes, thank you very much. i can use ThreadGroup.list.size can manage my threads. could you copy your answer to answer box, then i can choose your answer to be frozen. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a question about ThreadGroup (mentioned by @Phrogz) at [What is Ruby's ThreadGroup for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944500/what-is-rubys-threadgroup-for) .

Answer (score 0):

refer to @andrew-grimm answer:
There's a question about ThreadGroup (mentioned by @Phrogz) at [What is Ruby's ThreadGroup for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944500/)